# SyntaxError: invalid syntax while using find_element_by_xpath using Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, syntax-error

Code Trials:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.niftyindices.com/reports/historical-data")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id="ddlHistorical"]").send_keys("NIFTY 100")
```

I am getting an error:

```
File "<ipython-input-32-592f058980cd>", line 5
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id="ddlHistorical"]").send_keys("NIFTY 100")
                                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 3):

This error message...

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

...implies that the *xpath* expression was not a valid *xpath expression*.

As you are using *double quotes* i.e. **`"..."`** for the *xpath* you need to provide the *attribute values* within *single quotes* i.e. **`'...'`**.

So you need to change:

```
@id="ddlHistorical"
```

To:

```
@id='ddlHistorical'
```

Effectively the line of code:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id="ddlHistorical"]").send_keys("NIFTY 100")
```

will be:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='ddlHistorical']").send_keys("NIFTY 100")
```

Answer (score 2):

Send Keys can not be used in this case to select the value from drop down box:

```html
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Testing {
 public static WebDriver driver;

 @Test
 public void test() throws InterruptedException {
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./Driver/chromedriver");
  driver = new ChromeDriver();
  driver.get("http://www.niftyindices.com/reports/historical-data");
  driver.manage().window().maximize();
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(45, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"HistoricalData\"]/div[1]/div/div/a")).click();
  Thread.sleep(2000);
  List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"mCSB_2_container\"]/li"));
  for (WebElement element : elements) {
   String mCSB = element.getText();
   
   if (mCSB.equalsIgnoreCase("NIFTY 100"))
   {
    element.click();
   }
   System.out.println(mCSB);
  }
 }
}
```